# What is best practice to work with laravel 5.* project- localhost and server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

> Scenario 1

I develop laravel app in local host. And whenever i upload it to server i have to change index.php and public folder. This seems weird! In localhost i use public_path() for image upload but after uploading to server i have to change it to base_path()! This also seems weird too! If i have so many file where i use the public_path() function, then ? Here xampp is not mendatory to run but "php artisan serve"

> Scenario 2

Recently i learned virtual host in localhost. In this scenario i have to run my app from htdocs folder and using xampp running. here i have to change laravel original structure like: index.php from public folder and all file from public folder have to move out to main path. In this scenario i have to do nothing after uploading to server. 
But here a problem: to all other project in htdocs i have to mention in host file and httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Now i want to know which one is best and you follow. Or any other procedure you follow to maintain your laravel 5.* project?

Comment: You're doing the configuration on the server entirely wrong.  
What server and OS are you on?

Comment: At least on loclahost, I 100% recommends you Docker. It is not easy to do at first time, but it is really powerful. You will not depend on anything.

Comment: Is it something like Git? or what? @ matiaslauriti

Comment: I am using  cpanel(server) and windows 8.1@Koushik Das